# Parent model specific id column in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, rails-activerecord

Considering the following

```
:company has_many :issues  #ticket tracking example
```

I'd like to have routing such that any user in the company can go to /issues/:id (which is simple enough when using the default id column).

However, i'd like instead to have an issue id specific to the company (so each company would have their own issue 1, 2, 3 etc that isn't unique (and wouldn't use the internal id).

Is there any better way than calculating an id based on the last number in the db in the create and update actions in IssueController for that company id?  (I can think of various issues here with race conditions when multiple records are being updated/created per company).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want an `issue` to have a composite primary key made up of 'id' and 'company_id'?

Comment: Unsure what the best way to get this working is (though I can certainly hack something together) - i.e. when a request comes in to /issues/5701, @issue = Issue.where(company_id: current_user.company.id, issue_id: params[:id]).  I'm more concerned with whether that's the best way to store this kind of thing in the database to begin with (and the aforementioned db lookup to get next available issue_id for that company feel horrible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take the `issue_id` handling down to the model level. You can use a before_validation callback to set the `issue_id`. This alone, even though the `save` call is wrapped in a transaction, won't prevent race conditions. You have to further ensure the uniqueness of the couple `[ :company_id, :issue_id ]` by adding a index/unique constraint to your `issues` table, as suggested by @PinnyM. So something like this

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :company_id, :issue_id
  belongs_to :company
  before_validation :set_issue_id

  private
    def set_issue_id
      self.issue_id = self.company.issues.size + 1
    end
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :issues
end
```

and inside a migration:

```
add_index :issues, [:issue_id, :company_id], :unique => true
```

And you could grab the correct issue in the controller like you said:

```
@issue = Issue.where(company_id: current_user.company.id, issue_id: params[:id])
```

Note that this doesn't provide a way to recover from a constraint violation exception in case that actually happened. See @PinnyM answer for a suggestion on how to handle this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is subject to the same race conditions the OP wanted to avoid...  `issues.size` does not guarantee uniqueness even when wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? The only problem would be if `issues.size` changed after being assigned to issue_id and before the record is saved, but that can't happen right?

Comment: Multiple requests can be creating issues while the validation is executing. They will each be assigned the same 'issue_id' since the current `company.issues` collection size is the same, even though they are distinct records.

Comment: "but that can't happen right?" - it certainly can happen.  A transaction doesn't lock the table to ensure other records aren't created (unless you use table locking), it simply guarantees that the db 'snapshot' at the time the transaction begins does not change within the transaction context.

Comment: I think I get it, thanks for the explanation! Would making the company_id/issue_id couple unique fix that?

Comment: It would fix the problem from occurring, but it won't provide a nice way to retry if the race condition actually occurs.  It also won't help if you add a `uniqueness` constraint at the model level - this needs to be enforced at the DB level.

Comment: You are right again! This green tick is more yours than mine... I'll update the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

After misunderstanding the question the first time around, I'll take another shot at it.

You are looking for a way to have an issue 'counter' (to simulate an id) that is specific to a company_id.  Although @deivid was on the right track, relying on `issues.count` will only work if you can guarantee that a company never makes more than one request at a time.  This will generally be the case, but is not guaranteed and shouldn't be used alone as the core logic behind this counter.

You'll need to add a unique constraint/index to your `issues` table - this will ensure that counter can't be duplicated:

```
add_index :issues, [:issue_id, :company_id], :unique => true
```

Adding a `:uniqueness` constraint in the model will only mitigate the problem somewhat by making the window for the race condition smaller, but it can't guarantee uniqueness completely.

Note that in the event of a constraint violation in the DB, ActiveRecord can't recover from it within the transaction.  You can try rescuing `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`, recreating the `issue` (or just regenerating the `issue_id` using a fresh `count`) and saving again.

Comment: I think we should join both answers into one, as they are complementary. You can integrate my (corrected) code in to yours and I'll delete mine afterwards.

Comment: I appreciate your integrity, but you can simply copy the constraint information into your answer if you want this consolidated.